Django problem with downloading file from my computer
I am new to Django and I need some assistance. I want to download the file whose path is in plik.localisation (it has been taken from a loop). The problem is with the path. Could someone help me? What am I doing wrong?
My view.py is:
def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404

Urls
    path('download/<str:path>',views.download, name="download"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Html
<div class="com">
       {{plik.localisation}} <a href="{% url 'download/path' %}" class="button">download</a>
</div>

I've tried to change that path but still have problem with it.

1. There is no path() with the name 'download/path' in the urlpatterns list you shared so you will get a 404 HTTP response status when you click that anchor tag. There is "download" though. But what will be the argument for that View then? 2. If you use "download/path" as the argument for that View but you do not have a file "download/path" in your settings.MEDIA_ROOT, the if block will never be entered so you will get a 404 HTTP response status also. If you understood this comment I’ll write an answer but if you didn’t, ask for more clarification.

use FileResponse instead of HttpResponse

@ChukwujiobiCanon, could you write me a an answer, how should looks like? And also a href is wrong, I tried everyting.

Has this been solved?

Okay share the Model for the QuerySet plik.

`from django.db import models
class LokalizacjaPlikow(models.Model):
nazwa = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
lokalizacja = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
data = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nazwa
class Meta:
    db_table = 'lokalizacja_plikow'`


And the view is
`def download(path):                              #file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
if os.path.exists(path):
return FileResponse(open(path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(path))
raise Http404`


As you can see there is neither a FileField nor an ImageField nor any equivalent.

There is no path() with the name 'download/path' in your urlpatterns so you will get a 404 HTTP response status when you click that anchor tag.
What you want is:
<div class="com">
    <a href="{% url 'download' plik.localisation %}" class="button">download</a>
</div>

Aside:
Do you want to show the file as part of a webpage (considering that you are using header Content-Disposition: inline)? If so, why give the anchor tag a text that says "download"? If it is meant to be downloaded by the client, then this is what the server code should look like:
#•••Rest of code•••
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    return FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(file_path)) #[1]
If the file is meant to be shown as part of a webpage, then the anchor tag’s text shouldn’t be "download". That is misleading. It probably should be "view", "open" or any other variant of the same message since it won’t be downloaded. Then your code would be:
#•••Rest of code•••
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    return FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'), filename=os.path.basename(file_path))[2]

[1] The Content-Type header is automatically set when it can be guessed from the filename, or the name of open_file so no need for "application/pdf".
[2] as_attachment is False by default. Content-Disposition: inline will now be the header set.

I want to be downloaded by the client.
I still have problem with the url:
{{plik.localisation}} download
Reverse for 'download' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P[^/]+)/\Z']

The argument serve in your path() is for what by the way? If you want to pass extra keyword arguments to the View, it should look like this: some_arg=serve. But is serve defined? If it is a mistake, remove it and try again.

Os sorry, I already delete it, it looks like that:
'path('download//',views.download, name="download")'

Nope I have that info
Reverse for 'download' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P[^/]+)/\Z']

Make sure that plik.localisation has a valid value that is not "" —empty str. It is required not to be an empty str.

plik.localisation has a value for instance: F:\faktury\FS_18_IW1_03_2024.pdf
So probably that's the problem, so what can I do about it

Is that an absolute filesystem URL? I think it is. Windows OS uses that convention; "F:\", for drive letter names.

Yes that's right, so how can I pass the file path to function?

What is the guarantee that the file at that location is also located under settings.MEDIA_ROOT? I mean think about it. Is "faktury" == settings.MEDIA_ROOT? There’s just a lot to unpack.

There is no guarantee, hmm.. /n
Should it be? "faktury" == settings.MEDIA_ROOT
I am really confused now.

How did you come into possession of that file path?

It come from SQL database and it's shown by loop:

`{% for plik in obj %}


{{plik.nazwa}}


{{plik.data}}


{{plik.localisation}} pobierz
        </div>
    </div>`


"nazwa" or "localisation"? We have been using "localisation" all this while. I’ll take it that you know what you are doing. Since this value was a result of an upload to the database, Django stores file paths as absolute URLs in the database. This means that there is no need to resolve the path because it is already absolute. file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path) is of no use. Use path like that. Use path without first resolving. Do this: if os.path.exists(path): #•••Rest of code•••. Everywhere file_path was initially used, path will now be used.

I have tried nazwa because it is not a file path, and at least the program compile, so the plik.localisation is a problem becasue whole path can not be in url. Should it be like that then:But there is still problem in htmal file, there can't

def download(path):                              #file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)     with open(path, 'rb') as fh:         if os.path.exists(path):             return FileResponse(open(path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(path))

path('download/<path>/',views.download, name="download"), 

{{plik.lokalizacja}} <a href="{% url 'download' plik.lokalizacja %}" class="button">pobierz</a>

"…whole path can not be in url". You are absolutely right. So how do we communicate the path of the file to the server? Give me some time on this one. I’ll make a quick research.

Okay escape the plik.lokalizacja for use in URL. {% url 'download' plik.lokalizacja|urlencode %}

Chukwujiobi almost done. Now the terminal says:
TypeError: download() got multiple values for argument 'path'

Hmm that’s weird. You are only passing one argument; plik.lokalizacja|urlencode.

Is there a way we can see the resolved URL before it gets sent off to the server? Do this let’s see what the server receives: {% url 'download' plik.lokalizacja|urlencode as the_url %} {{ the_url }}. Value of the_url is the endpoint that gets hit. If there is an issue with that value, we can dissect it and know where to start in resolving the issue.

hmm still the same issue

I think if you use plik.lokalizacja insed of {{plik.lokalizacja}} you will get whole list from the loop

Did you do what I mentioned? What is the value of the_url? It should show in the browser before you click it. What does it show. Put it in any paragraph tag and show me what the value is. Do this: {% url 'download' plik.lokalizacja|urlencode as the_url %} <p>{{ the_url }}</p>.

Nope still the same issue ;(
TypeError: download() got multiple values for argument 'path'

This code works
def download(request, path):                             with open(path, 'rb') as fh: if os.path.exists(path): return FileResponse(open(path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename=os.path.basename(path)) raise Http404

That’s my code is it not? Without the with Context of course. You don’t even need the Context so remove it. So the path didn’t have to be concatenated with settings.MEDIA_URL after all just like I said. Well congrats. One upvote from me although I’ve got to say that I deserve the accepted answer after all I went through to get this to work. Cheers :)

The code has a redundancy issue. The file is opened twice. Also, the os.path.exists(path) check should be done before opening the file. Consider revising the code for efficiency and correctness.
